# Message bridge between TIBCO EMS and Solace EMS

Tags: message-queue, tibco, bridge, solace, ems

We are migrating from TIBCO EMS to Solace EMS and in order to minimize any disruption, we are trying to bridge the messages from TIBCO to Solace. Information from TIBCO Support is that messages cannot be routed to another JMS provider, however I find this improbable. Does anyone have any ideas how to connect both EMS systems?

Comment: I know this is late, but were you ever successful in finding a solution?  We are facing the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Solace has recently launched an integration tool called [HybridEdge](https://docs.solace.com/HybridEdge/HybridEdge.htm) which is based on [Apache Camel](http://camel.apache.org). Part of the Solace integration is a JMS component (Camel adapter). Using HybridEdge, you could easily set up a "route" (Camel flow) that has Tibco EMS via the Camel JMS component using the EMS JMS connectionFactory and bridge to Solace JMS via their component (which uses their JMS connectionFactory)

https://github.com/SolaceProducts/solace-hybridedge is where the Solace HybridEdge starter project is. It's an example of how you can get started with HybridEdge.

You would then use the Camel JMS component to connect to EMS. Info on the component is here: http://camel.apache.org/jms.html

Keep in mind that you are bridging 2 brokers through another middleware (the Camel Exchange)... this is bound to have more latency and less msgs/sec than you are used to with just EMS or Solace alone, especially with persistent messages that need to be ack'd all the way back.

Answer (score 0):

You could use 'forwarding channels' in **Replay for Messaging**: https://www.tradeweb.com/institutional/services/replayservice/

Replay for Messaging is a cross-provider Messaging Database and Messaging Bridge originally developed at CodeStreet, now owned by Tradeweb (Note: I work there). The ReplayServer is written in C++, so it's low-latency and you can quickly setup bridges between TIBCO EMS and Solace from the WebUI, also with optional Conversion, if needed.

The Replay function can help with testing during the migration process.